# How to read aggregations like sum, average at row labels instead of column labels in excel pivot table using apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have generated a pivot table, but I want to know how to obtain the average value for the column label field in the pivot table.

```
    CellReference ptStartCell = new CellReference("A3");
    AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference("A3:M"+num, null);

    XSSFSheet pivotSheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet");
    XSSFPivotTable pivotTable  =  pivotSheet.createPivotTable(areaReference, ptStartCell, sheet);
    pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
    pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
    pivotTable.addColLabel(3);

    pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM,10, "A");
    pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM,11, "B");
    pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM,12, "C");
    pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE,6, "D");
    pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM,9, "E");
```

Comment: You can't. All Apache POI does using XSSFSheet.createPivotTable` is creating a pivot table draft. Excel's GUI then uses that draft to render the pivot table. And only while that the sums and avarage are calculated. Apache POI has no access to that values.